# Unable to use gmail account for ssrs email subscription

Tags: iis, sql-server-2008-r2, gmail, rs

On a stand alone Windows 7 Professional PC with SQL Server 2008 R2 installed I want RS (Report Server) subscriptions to email reports through my gmail account. I have looked through all of the help at StackOverflow but nothing has helped. I have been trying to configure my gmail account, RS email and IIS version 7.5.7600.16385. Just in case, I am connected to the web via a router and an ISP. Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help.

Currently, I am receiving the following error: Failure sending mail: At least one recipient is required, but none were found. Mail will not be resent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the Reporting Services Configuration Manager and set the "E-Mail Settings" ?   This is where you would provide an SMTP server.  Set it to smtp.gmail.com.